# I can't properly export a variable from one file to another

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access the `server` variable in `app.js` from `io.js`. When I place the code in the io.js file directly in app.js it works fine. But as soon as I seperate the two it doesn't seem to work despite the `module.export` line.

app.js:

```
var server = http.Server(app)
module.exports = server
```

io.js:

```
var server = require('./app')
var io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' })
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  })
})
```

Am I using the export function incorrectly, or is this just not possible?

Comment: you can export it by making function in app.js

Comment: use this in app.js `module.exports = function() {
  return  http.Server(app);
};` i hope it work for you

Comment: Doesn't appear to, I even tried ...return server...

Comment: what error you got while use this code and your code?

Comment: do you have app variable declare in app.js

Comment: The error comes from the 404 error received when the client tries to connect. Not directly as an error when the server is started.

Comment: app variable declare, do you mean: `var app = express()` ?

Comment: may be it is not available inside function